# Why is Shanks a Yonko?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece, Shanks doesn't have any Devil Fruit power.

Also, he lost an arm while saving Luffy.

What makes him a Yonko ?

For Example

> Whitebeard had a powerful Devil Fruit. But even without that, his physical
>   strength was tremendous.

Can anyone please explain what made Shanks a Yonko?

Comment: Because he's strong enough to duel Mihawk with one hand and can counter Whitebeard attack. He don't need to be DF user. He's crazy strong.

Comment: vista is also strong enough to duel with mihawk which we saw during the war . does this make vista a yonko ? and whitebear hit him only using physical power not DF power

Comment: We never see the battle but Mihawk respect Shanks as his rival and the duel is longer than Vista. Become a non DF user doesn't mean he's weaker than them. We already saw Zorro or Sanji defeat lots of DF user using only their strength.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've been reading this manga from it's beginning. I think we can all agree that we haven't seen enough of Shanks powers. But, let's see some examples of him demonstrating his powers:

When we first saw him with Luffy (in the first episode) and we see little of his fighting skills, mostly just his spirit, which he demonstrates against [Higuma](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Higuma) and then to the Sea King where, he demonstrates [his Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Haoshoku_Haki).

Then after 10 years, with only one arm left, he is been visited by [Mihawk](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mihawk) on an island. We all know Mihawk is the best swordsman in the OP world. A guy won't just cozy up to any ordinary pirate after all for a drink, in celebration of Luffy's first bounty.

After which we learn that they've had regular matches with one another, which means in terms of powers he has to be very strong to be a match for Mihawk. Also then he demonstrates that he can take a blow from the [Yonko](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kaido). And when he entered the Whitebeard's ship his haki not only knocked out a lot of [Whitebeard's crew](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Whitebeard_Pirates), but also damaged the ship. Also this caused [Whitebeard](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Whitebeard)'s scar to ache and have [Marco](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Marco) and [Jozu](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Jozu) commend about his spirit.

Also before the Summmit War Arc he was fighting another Yonko, [Kaido](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kaido), which According to Law, he is "the strongest creature in the world" and an ally of [Donquixote Doflamingo](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Donquixote_Doflamingo).

After that events, we saw him in Summit War Arc where he stopped [Akainu](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Akainu) with [Armament haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Busoshoku_Haki). And then he asked Blackbeard which until then he didn't fear anyone to fight (Whitebeard, was an exception) and he said that it's not time yet for them to fight. He understood on that moment he isn't ready to fight Shanks, which it means a lot, since he stopped the war, even Sengoku respects.

While Shanks hasn't been in a lot of fights and Oda haven't show us yet Shank's skills, from the above mentioned facts, I think we can all agree that he deserves to be amongst the Yonko.

Also It's not just him that's strong, his crew members are too, [Ben Beckman](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Benn_Beckman) was able to make Kizaru stop for a moment during the Summit War Arc.

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: About shank's conquerors Haki. [Oda confirmed that on fishman island, he would have been able to take down all 100.000 fishman if he would have released Haki instead of Luffy's 50.000.](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_65#Chapter_642.2C_Page_126) Showing how great his willpower is.

Answer (score 8):

He is considered a Yonko for the following reasons:

- Can use all three types of Haki
- Was the rival of the [**Greatest Swordsman in the World**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Dracule_Mihawk)
- Has a deadly crew
- Can break a **ship** with his wave of Haki
- Has the guts to mock the strongest man by making members of his (supposedly the strongest) crew faint.
- Challenged Mihawk (the strongest swordsman) and Newgate (the strongest man alive) even **without an arm**
- Challenged everyone after the war: the three Admirals, the Fleet Admiral, overshadowed old school player Garp, Blackbeard (who had the strongest Logia and strongest Paramecia), but yet no one stepped forward!
- Convinced Marines to end the war with no further casualties single-handedly
- Was able to stop Kaido before time and head to stop the war (probably made Kaido, the strongest Beast, retreat) during the Marineford arc, as stated on the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Shanks#Marineford_Arc).
- Was considered to be one of the few people capable of defeating Blackbeard by the Gorosei
- Has yet to demonstrate his full powers, yet dreaded as the dangerous Yonko.

If you still think he is not capable of being called as Yonko just because he has no Devil Fruit or doesn't shown his might like what Whitebeard does, then what would you say about Kaido and Big Mom?
I think he is the strongest non-Devil Fruit user of the series!

Comment: What did you mean by `Was considered to be one of the few people capable of defeating Blackbeard by the Gorosei`

Comment: See here>>http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Shanks#Abilities_and_Powers      The second or third last line of the first para! After the marineford arc the Gorosei discussed about the people capable of stopping Blackbeard and Shanks was one of them! This page will make it clearer>>http://www.mangapanda.com/one-piece/594/2   ... All the three remaining yonko,Marco and remnant of WB pirates are capable of stopping him... Although I feel all the rest admirals ,Garp,ex-admirals,Fleet-admirals and ex-fleet admiral and Sengoku are among the other people except the pirates who are capable of stopping BB!

Comment: @Entei read the previous comment